# How to get @everyone role ID?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I need to get @everyone role ID to create a private chat for to server members (I'll restrict others except for those 2 users from reading and sending messages). How?

I tried typing

```
\@Admin
```

to get Admin's role ID as an example.
But then I typed

```
\@everyone
```

and it creates a regular message mentioning everyone on the server (like typing `@everyone` in chat). No ID.

How do I get @everyone role ID?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<s>The ID for the `everyone` role is the Guild ID.

If you try to do `<@&123123>` replacing `123123` with your guild id, it will *almost* tag everyone</s>

---

**Update: 10th April 2020**

Now to mention everyone, all you need is to send the string @everyone: `message.channel.send("@everyone");`

---

To obtain the ID for the everyone role, you need to have the **guild**, which you get on some events like: `message`, `guildCreate`, and others.
From there: [`<something>.guild.roles.everyone`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=everyone), and with that you should be able to get the ID with `<something>.guild.roles.everyone.id`.

If you don't have access to the guild on a event, you can get the guild by it's ID with something like:
`client.guilds.cache.get('guildID').roles.everyone.id`, if you know that it will be in cache. If you want to be safe, you can do it like this:

```
client.guilds.fetch('guildID').then(guild => { 
    let id = guild.roles.everyone.id;
    // do something with id
}
```

or with await:

```
let guild = await client.guilds.fetch('guildID');
let id = guild.roles.everyone.id;
```

Comment: It creates like this `@@everyone`

Comment: The question is not "how to mention everyone". It's "how to get everyone role id". It doesn't really answer (I think?)

Comment: @JackRed I've updated my answer with more options now :)

Comment: @André Yes thanks. However it doesn't really help. The "guildID" you mention is the same as the everyone role ID (this is how Discord work). If you go with dev mode activated and do right click > copy ID on the server icon, you'll have the same ID as when going in the roles settings and copying everyone role ID. This can also be checked when writting <@&GuildID>, which will translate to the mention of the role everyone (doesn't totally work tho, compared when other role, probably because it's a special role + the existence of @here)

Comment: The TL;DR of my comment being, if you have the GuildID, you have the everyone role ID since it's the same

Comment: sending just the text @everyone doesn't seem to actually ping people

Answer (score 2):

## Discord.js

### V12

The `guild` class has a [`roles`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=roles) property, which is a [`RoleManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager).
This manager has the property `everyone`:

> The @everyone role of the guild

You can get its id with the id property of the role class:

```js
client.on('message', (msg) => {
  console.log(msg.guild.roles.everyone.id);
});
```

### V11

In V11 the `guild` class has a [`defaultRole`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=defaultRole) property.

So the code is slightly different:

```js
client.on('message', (msg) => {
  console.log(msg.guild.defaultRole.id);
});
```

## Discord

On Discord side, with dev option activated, you can right click in almost everything to grab it ID. For example go in the server settings, in role and right click on a role, you should have a `copy ID` option.

Answer (score 2):

Need to get @everyone Role?

```js
<guild>.roles.everyone
```

It will get a role object. You can check that in [Role Class](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role)